# node distance=6mm and 25mm?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In Brent Longboroughs TikZ-based [Easy-maintenance flowchart](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/flexible-flow-chart), somewhere one can read:

```
node distance=6mm and 25mm
```

What does **`and 25mm`** mean here?

Comment: Looks like space for vertical nodes and then for horizontal nodes.

Comment: Thanks, @Sigur. Do you know the spot in the Pgf manual where this is documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When positioning a node  e.g. `below right` of another node, the first value is the vertical shift, and the second value is the horizontal shift. See section *17.5.3 Advanced Placement Options* in the manual.

A small example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (3,3);
\node (a) at (0,0) {A};

\node [above right=of a] {B};

\begin{scope}[node distance=2cm and 1cm] %default is 1cm and 1cm
\node [above right=of a] {C};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

They are spaces for rows and columns. See what happens when we change it to `node distance=2mm and 20mm`.

[image]

Comment: Happy to see that, even though the result is a mess, the *connections* still work! (Almost)